# AWS SAM Glue job including python script

Tags: aws-glue, aws-sam

I'm looking at automating the creation of my glue job (including the python script) in an AWS SAM app. I understand it's possible to reference a glue script in S3, I'm looking for a way to include the creation of the S3 zip containing the python code in the sam app too, without having to create it outside of SAM. From what I've been reading it looks like the only way is to create the zip separately from the SAM app?

Ideally everything would update at once on sam deploy, like it would when creating a lambda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I'm going to create a python script to:

- copy files over to s3
- run sam deploy commands

That way it's still only one command to run to deploy sam, and have all the latest glue scripts in place.

Answer (score 2):

Just to include another option, it is possible to create a Macro for CloudFormation adding a new resource "AWS::S3::Object" which contains the Glue script inline.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/S3Objects

```
Transform: S3Objects

Resources:
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  Object1:
    Type: AWS::S3::Object
    Properties:
      Target:
        Bucket: !Ref Bucket
        Key: README.md
        ContentType: text/markdown
      Body: |
        # My text file
        
        This is my text file;
        there are many like it,
        but this one is mine.

  Object2:
    Type: AWS::S3::Object
    Properties:
      Target:
        Bucket: !Ref Bucket
        Key: 1-pixel.gif
        ACL: public-read
        ContentType: image/png
      Base64Body: R0lGODdhAQABAIABAP///0qIbCwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=
```

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks! I love the full metal jacket quote too :)